# appcompat v21 toolbar and actionmode not working

Tags: android, material-design

I have a root fragment with the following toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar" />
```

i then proceeded to setting the toolbar as the support actionbar:

```
ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity)getActivity();
activity.setSupportActionBar();
```

When calling `activity.startSupportActionMode(callback)`, non of the callbacks are ever fired and the actionMode is never started.

Playing around with it i've discovered that using `mToolbar.startActionMode(callback)` does work, but i can't use that because of compatibility also the material design styles doesn't seem to work when using the native actionmode